# Why does InDesign paste my copied image from AI with an unproportional resize frame?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, images

Often when pasting an image into ID copied from AI. It gives me a larger frame than it supposed to. For e.g Normally there would be a rectangular/square frame around the object to resize, however at times this re-size box is way too big. I have to also add that this mainly happens when i have multiple images on an artboard in AI and select just one object. It's almost as if i have copied a transparent image/s next the one i want. Is this a bug or is there a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Several causes spring to mind. You could have some object in Illustrator hidden. It's still part of a Group or Symbol so it comes along, but since its turned off, the location is making the dimensions larger. Alternatively, it could be a Guide placed in Illustrator. Same deal as any layer — they could be grouped incorrectly and thus come along for the ride. It could also be something to do with Clipping or Compound paths; if what you see is the correct size, the empty space around it could be the constituent paths. 

Poke around in your Illustrator object and try to clean up the elements.

Comment: i will try all that, and report back. Seems to me that there might be the problem in all that you have pointed out.

Comment: @scottperezfox Back. And with good news!! Thank you for giving me a direction to go on. I really made sure i didn't leave any of your points out and so i really thought hard on all possibilities. In the end, after trying almost everything, i realised there could be stray points, even though i didn't see any when i selected the entire image, which is why i disregarded this. (that and also the fact i'm working with just vectors/shapes).

The solution was with: Selection > Object > Stray Points. And i simply just hit delete. Voila! When i copy my image/object to Indesign the correct size box is s

Comment: @scottperezfox You should put that comment into an answer so it can be approved! And Alexander, you should approve his answer when he'll add it by clicking the diamond icon on his answer :) And then we can all rejoice yay!

Answer (score 1):

Several causes spring to mind. You could have some object in Illustrator hidden. It's still part of a Group or Symbol so it comes along, but since its turned off, the location is making the dimensions larger. Alternatively, it could be a Guide placed in Illustrator. Same deal as any layer — they could be grouped incorrectly and thus come along for the ride. It could also be something to do with Clipping or Compound paths; if what you see is the correct size, the empty space around it could be the constituent paths. Poke around in your Illustrator object and try to clean up the elements.

Alternatively, it could be a stray point. To remove those, try `Selection > Object > Stray Points`

Answer (score 0):

don't use copy/paste--always use the place command in Indesign.

sorry that really didn't answer your ques--this will--when you copy/paste from illustrator--the vectors will be editable vector elements in Indesign--the reason no resize box is there--is because Indesign see the vectors as having been created in Indesign so there is no frame--if you want to proportionally resize--make your art on separate artboards in Illus--then use the 'place' command in Indesign and 'tick' the check box that says 'show import options'

Comment: I agree with the sentiment that Placing is superior to copy-pasting, but let's try to help him solve the issue.

Comment: i guess that is very helpful for a different situation. i will keep that in mind. Thank you so much. However it doesn't help me here because i need to copy/paste as i need to have editable images in InDesign, i am working on something that i am constantly copy and pasting images to InDesign. And also the place works best for actual images i guess i meant i'm working with simple vector line art. sorry.

Comment: Thanks @scottperezfox. Is there a solution to this. or must i use the --very-- long workaround which is create artwork in numerous artboards ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about multiple artboards. Maybe you should post an entirely new question because that topic is important in both InDesign and Illustrator.

Comment: what I mean by multiple artboards is to keep the various graphics (in Illustrator) separate so when you place them (with show import options checked) you have a choice of what area gets imported--if the illustrator elements need to be edited then open the illustrator file--make edit(s) if indesign file is still open--links should update immediately